# Como revierto cambios despues de hacer push en git

Tags: git, github, git-push, github-desktop

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo volver a una version anterior del codigo. Tras hacer Push he hecho una serie de cambios, los cuales no puedo revertir con Ctrl+z, por lo cual querria saber si es posible volver al punto donde he hecho el último Push en Github Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digamos que el último commit que hiciste en la rama local es el que está en la rama remota y quieres revertir los cambios que hiciste en el árbol de trabajo y que no estan *acometidos*... en ese caso, lo más sencillo es hacer un `restore`:

```
git restore --worktree --staged --source=HEAD -- .
```

También se podría hacer con un hard-reset:

```
gir reset --hard
```

Con cualquiera de las dos formas, vas a perder los cambios en los archios que no hayas acometido y vas a limpiar el index también.... así que usar con precaución.

Si ya has acometido cosas en la rama local y quieres eliminarlas y dejar tu rama como está en la rama remota (tanto en historia como en contenido), entonces hay que hacer un hard-reset como este:

```
git reset --hard <el-remoto>/<la-rama-remota>
```

Esto remueve los commits que hiciste en la rama local, obviamente, para lograr que las dos historias sean las mismas.

Si quieres hacer lo último *pero* sin borrar la historia de los commits que hiciste localmente, entonces puedes hacer esto:

```
git restore --worktree --staged --source=<el-remoto>/<la-rama-remota> -- .
git commit -m "Regresando a un commit anterior" # ajusta el comentario
```

Con eso te queda la historia que hiciste de los commits locales y en un solo commit regresas *el contenido* del proyecto a lo que hay en la rama remota.

Answer (score 0):

Existe un comando para volver a una versión anterior de tu proyecto:

```
git reset ...
```

Lee la [documentación oficial](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) para hacerlo correctamente. También puedes ver ejemplos de `git revert` que es un alternativa a valorar en este [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).